# C# Ошибка при вызове переменной из Static класса

Tags: c#

Есть код

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Configs
{
    public static class Config
    {
        public static bool test = true;
    }
```

при обращению к нему

```
using ConsoleApp1.Configs;

if (Config.test) //<<< ошибка Метод или операция не реализована
{ 
    do somthing
}
```

происходит ошибка

> InnerException {"Метод или операция не реализована."} 
>   System.Exception {System.NotImplementedException}

подскажите пожалуйста что не так?

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится.

Comment: Целиком вставьте код вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каком наймспейсе и классе вы вызываете Config.test?

```
public class testclass 
{ 
  public void somemethod()
  {
    if (Config.test) 
    { do }
  }
}
```

Comment: Больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ :)

Comment: Согласен, ошибся немного

Comment: using ConsoleApp1.Configs;
namespace ConsoleApp1.Common
{
  public class testclass
  {
  if (Config.test)
{ 
    do somthing
}

}

как то так

Comment: Вы не можете использовать эту конструкцию сразу в классе testclass. Если вы к примеру создадите метод, и будете её использовать внутри, то все будет работать нормально